# Determine if URL is Sharepoint without Sharepoint API

Tags: sharepoint, url, ssis

I'm building an SSIS package resposible for importing an Excel file sourced either from Sharepoint or from a "regular" directory.  Given a random URL, is there a way to determine if it's a Sharepoint URL or just a regular directory (public path or local subdirectory)?  The SSIS package does not have access to Microsoft.Sharepoint.  I'm guessing I'd have to use some form of a Sharepoint Web method, but I'm not sure if there is one that would suit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharepoint generally lists itself in various ways in the generated pages meta tags:

```
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" />
<meta name="progid" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" />
<META Name="CollaborationServer" Content="SharePoint Team Web Site">
```

This might not hold for totally custom page templates, but on the default out-of-the-box stuff, it does.